# Microsoft bot framework for teams capturing unique user id

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are building a product integration using ms teams and ms bots. We are having an existing integration with Slack already. In the slack World we identify a unique user by TEAM_ID and USER_ID . In case of Teams I can see even id in the from node is a very long string suggesting its unique. Below payload is one example coming to our server. Can someone confirm if using id from the from node is wont change a particular user ever?

the user id being assumed unqiue to a user below is "29:1374Bmi6ngJLBlF9oGVcDuTaBbMfJmcOF9eUvQVdx_rgYh5spPNQ5Mi6fLdVvCiT7mQPMNytT0zGk_iAUtvqKAwXXXX"

```
{
  "_activity": {
    "id": "1576102076169",
    "from": {
      "id": "29:1374Bmi6ngJLBlF9oGVcDuTaBbMfJmcOF9eUvQVdx_rgYh5spPNQ5Mi6fLdVvCiT7mQPMNytT0zGk_iAUtvqKAwXXXX",
      "name": "My Name",
      "aadObjectId": "37a2516a-baf2-41d8-a406-a067888d676c"
    },
    "conversation": {
      "conversationType": "personal",
      "tenantId": "9bfb3569-994e-4908-855c-c7f6c1a94100",
      "id": "a:1DcGjCAgiuinvuzR0Mx6dR9uJOB3YUwjMdLOiGTAwQ7KWSGsiEijNfvir66ep7k0fABwoSXxCAACx2_3GflfTNIZL7XMkfjrMm0v8OzJJ7vvIFKasqrClrZ_T-8dDfdT0"
    },
    "channelData": {
      "tenant": {
        "id": "9bfb3569-994e-4908-855c-c7f6c1a94100"
      }
    },
    "text": "contact mat",
    "textFormat": "plain",
    "type": "message",
    "channelId": "msteams",
    "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer/",
    "recipient": {
      "id": "28:a835cf1d-83a8-4ae9-845a-23a68a1df442",
      "name": "FlashCX.ai"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Moblize IT Yes the id obtained from activity.from.id is the unique id for user and it wont change.